# nginx listen directive confusion

Tags: nginx, server

I am trying to configure nginx i m trying to find how listen `directive` in `server` block works.
 suppose i have this config:

```
server {
        listen 192.168.11.12:80;
       }
```

Does it mean nginx will `listen` for requests on `port 80` which is coming from `ip: 192.168.11.22` . or does it mean it will listen on ip `192.168.11.12` and on port `80`. I searched for docs but they simply mention how server block works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second one, it will listen on that ip and port.

Comment: thaks reply but how doees it exactly makes sense . say i have a `system A` with ip:`192.168.11.12` and my `nginx` is running on this host. what other values can ip part take other than `192.168.11.12`.

Comment: If you have a system with multiple ips, then you can use this field to select which ip to bind to.